# Unable to Allow IP Address Through VPC Service Controls on Google Cloud Platform[Artifact Registry Perimeter]

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to allow access to a specific IP address through VPC Service Controls on Google Cloud Platform, but it is still being blocked by the organization's policy. I have created an access level with the appropriate IP range and have verified that VPC Service Controls and firewall rules are properly configured. However, the IP address is still being blocked with the error message "Request is prohibited by organization's policy."

Here are some additional details about my setup:

- Resource: Artifact Registry API
- Access Level: 49.36.189.5/32
- Ingress Rule: None
- Egress Rule: None

I always get `NO_MATCHING_ACCESS_LEVEL` whilst troubleshooting.

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 7,
      "message": "Request is prohibited by organization's policy. vpcServiceControlsUniqueIdentifier: ...",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure",
          "violations": [
            {
              "type": "VPC_SERVICE_CONTROLS",
              "description": "..."
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {},
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "49.36.189.5"
    },
    "serviceName": "artifactregistry.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "artifactregistry.googleapis.com/DockerRead",
    "resourceName": "projects/...",
    "metadata": {
      "vpcServiceControlsUniqueId": "...",
      "deviceState": "Unknown",
      "ingressViolations": [
        {
          "targetResource": "projects/...",
          "servicePerimeter": "accessPolicies/.../servicePerimeters/artifact_registry"
        }
      ],
      "securityPolicyInfo": {
        "organizationId": "...",
        "servicePerimeterName": "accessPolicies/.../servicePerimeters/artifact_registry"
      },
      "violationReason": "NO_MATCHING_ACCESS_LEVEL",
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.VpcServiceControlAuditMetadata",
      "resourceNames": [
        "projects/workbench/locations/asia-south2/repositories/linkerd"
      ]
    }
  },
  "insertId": "...",
  "resource": {
    "type": "audited_resource",
    "labels": {
      "method": "artifactregistry.googleapis.com/DockerRead",
      "service": "artifactregistry.googleapis.com",
      "project_id": "workbench"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-04-17T19:41:53.980508385Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/workbench/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fpolicy",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-04-17T19:41:54.653154845Z"
}
```

There are no organization policies that restrict access based on IP addresses or other criteria.
I have followed all the steps in the documentation, but I am still unable to allow access to the IP address. Can anyone provide suggestions on what might be causing this issue or how to further troubleshoot it?

Comment: It would be best to be in touch with the [Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/contact) so they can further inspect your project

Comment: Could you share the list of activate organization policy to this project ? `gcloud resource-manager org-policies list --project=<PROJECT ID>`

Answer (score 0):

After days of struggle, I finally found the solution given by AlexKhaerov here:

- https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/General-Misc-Q-A/Could-not-access-services-with-Access-Context-Manager-VPC/m-p/607958/highlight/true#M1124

The key difference is the `scope` of the `access policy`: There MUST exist an org-level (non-scoped) policy.